# Understanding static method in laravel Model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I was just going through a laravel tutrorial online and i saw the following modal coded as below:

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Notice extends Model {

    protected $fillable = [
        'provider_id',
        'infringing_title',    
        'infringing_link',    
        'original_link',    
        'original_description',    
        'template',    
        'content_removed'
    ];


    public static function open(array $attributes) {
        return new static($attributes); 
    } 

    public function useTemplate($template) {
        $this->template = $template;
    }

}
```

What i am interested to know is what exactly is the use of the below method that is defined:

```
public static function open(array $attributes) {
            return new static($attributes); 
}
```

I realize its a static method , but this line `return new static($attributes);` particularly confuses me.

I see the method being used in the following way:

```
    $notice = Notice::open($date);
```

But i still don't quite understand its usage . can somebody explain .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

static method can be used without instantiating the class thus the `::`

`return new static($attributes);` makes a new model object from that class

which is basically the same as

```
$notice = new Notice;
$notice->provider_id = $provider_id;
...
```

all you need to do with the object insatance is call `$notice->save()`

Answer (score 2):

In this case it is just a syntactic sugar. Someone doesn't seem to like the `new` keyword and prefers a more semantic way to instantiate a new notice class, so it reads better.

It also leaves you the doors open for some future logic around instantiating new notice.

Btw. it is mod**e**l, not mod**a**l.